# Convenient way to slice from multiindexed rows based on range of keys at different levels with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I have a multiindexed pandas dataframe sort of like this:

```
data = np.random.random((1800,9))
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A','B','C'),('a','b','c')])

year = range(2006,2011)
month = range(1,13)
day = range(1,31)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([year,month,day], names=['Year','Month','Day'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, idx, col)
```

Which has multiindexed rows of `Year`, `Month`, `Day`. I want to be able to select rows from this Dataframe as if it were one that has a DatetimeIndex.

The equivalent DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex would be:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2006-01-01', end='2010-12-31', freq='d')
timeidx = [ix for ix in idx if ix.day < 29]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, timeidx, col)
```

What I would like is this:

```
all(df2.ix['2006-06-06':'2008-10-11'] == df1'insert expression here')
```

to equal `True`

I know I can select cross-sections via `df1.xs('2006', level='Year')`, but I basically need an easy way to replicate what was done for `df2` as I am forced to use this index as opposed to the DatetimeIndex.

Comment: couldn't you just make a new column that combines the other three? or is this not feasible in your case

Comment: I wish! In my case I have dates ranging from year 1850-2300 (DatetimeIndex is limited to year 2263) and with different calendars such as 360-day and other variations so PeriodIndex won't work either. This approach was suggested as an alternative in a few different places however I need to be able to do similar indexing in my work.

Comment: Oh nevermind I see what you're getting at. Yes that would work but I would have to load the data from a .csv with those three columns as index and everytime a file is saved they would need to be put back into the index. Maybe there is another way that is straightforward enough.

Comment: can you just add a full date field column to the csv? that'd be easy/fast to do with some simple command line things

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you mean to add a column that consists of timestamps ie. `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM` to index on with pandas? If so this will not work for the dates that I have

Comment: For example if a certian calendar has February 30th in it then this will not work hence why I want to try to index on the Year, Month, Day multiindex

Comment: One issue you'll immediately have by storing these as strings is `'2' > '10'`, which is almost certainly not what you want, so I recommend using ints. I'm *sure* there is a way to do this slice... but can't recall.

Comment: @Andy Good call. They can be set as int without any trouble I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue you'll immediately have by storing these as strings is `'2' > '10'`, which is almost certainly not what you want, so I recommend using ints. That is:

```
year = range(2006,2011)
month = range(1,13)
day = range(1,31)
```

I though that you ought to be able to use pd.IndexSlice here, my first thought was to use it as follows:

```
In [11]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [12]: df1.loc[idx[2006:2008, 6:10, 6:11], :]
...
```

**but** this shows those between 2006-8 and june-oct and 6-11th (ie 3*5*6 = 90 days).

---

So here's a non-vectorized way, just compare the tuples:

```
In [21]: df1.index.map(lambda x: (2006, 6, 6) < x < (2008, 10, 11))
Out[21]: array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [22]: df1[df1.index.map(lambda x: (2006, 6, 6) < x < (2008, 10, 11))]
# just the (844) rows you want
```

---

If this was unbearably slow, a trick (to vectorize) would be to use some float representation, for example:

```
In [31]: df1.index.get_level_values(0).values + df1.index.get_level_values(1).values * 1e-3 + df1.index.get_level_values(2).values * 1e-6
Out[31]:
array([ 2006.001001,  2006.001002,  2006.001003, ...,  2010.012028,
        2010.012029,  2010.01203 ])
```

Comment: I guess the float representation comes with the usual epsilon warning for float slicing.

Comment: So that's how map works. Looks promising I'll have to test later on my desktop.